# Determine most popular Hue of an image with HSV Histogram Emgu CV 3.0.0.2158

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Here is the code I am working with currently

```
Image<Hsv, byte> hsvImage = tempImage.Convert<Hsv, byte>();
Image<Gray, byte>[] channels = hsvImage.Split();
Image<Gray, byte> hue = channels[0];

DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(255, new RangeF(0, 255));

hist.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { hue }, true, null);

double[] minV, maxV;
Point[] minL, maxL;
hist.MinMax(out minV, out maxV, out minL, out maxL); //only gets lowest and highest, not most popular
```

Now I use the maxL[0].Y and I have some ranges set up to find out what color it is, but these arent numbers I can just pull out of the image directly.  My question is, is there a way to find the most used color with a histogram or will I have to convert the image to black and white and look for the colors I want?

Comment: what's _most popular_ or _more used_? It's not just the max in histogram?

Comment: I guess more used would make more sense.  In the histogram, at least the way Im using it, it will only give me the min or the max not the most used

Comment: the more frequent value in the histogram _is_ the more used, unless _used_ has a different meaning for you

Comment: my meaning of most used is say 51% of an area is Red I want something to pop out the hue that is equivalent to that red.

Comment: The position `maxL` is the index to your _most used_ color

Comment: ok, I will keep using that then.  Thank you!